# Static list MINUS select statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a java program that returns a list of Long values (hundreds).
I would like to subtract to this list the values obtained from a select on an oracle database,
something like this:

```
SELECT 23 as num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17 as num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 19 as num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 67 as num FROM DUAL UNION ALL...
...
...
SELECT 68 as num FROM DUAL MINUS
SELECT NUM FROM MYTABLE
```

I presume that this operation has some performance issues...
Are there other better approaches?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:**

Use Global Temporary Tables (GTT):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  column1  NUMBER
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Insert the List (Long value) into `my_temp_table`:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO my_temp_table (column1) VALUES (27)
   INTO my_temp_table (column1) VALUES (32)
   INTO my_temp_table (column1) VALUES (25)
   .
   .
   .
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM my_temp_table 
WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT NUM FROM MYTABLE);
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

---

**Case 2:**

Use TYPE table:

```
CREATE TYPE number_tab IS TABLE OF number;

SELECT column_value AS num
FROM TABLE (number_tab(1,2,3,4,5,6)) temp_table
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYTABLE.NUM = temp_table.num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MyTable is much bigger than literal values, I think the best option is using a temporary table to store your values. This way your query is a lot cleaner.

If you are working in a concurrent environment (e.g. typical web app), use an id field, and delete when finished. Summarizing:

- preliminary: create a table for temporary values TEMPTABLE(id, value)
- for each transaction

  - get new unique/atomic id (new oracle sequence value, for example)
  - for each literal value: insert into temptable(new_id, value)
  - select * from temptable where id = new_id minus...
  - process result
  - delete from temp_table where id = new_id

Temporary tables are a good solution in oracle. This one can be used with an ORM persistence layer